# Rake: how to output a list of tasks from inside a task?

Tags: ruby, rake

I'd like my :default task in a Rakefile to be a helpful message that also includes the list of available tasks (the output of rake -T) for people who are not as familiar with rake.

How do you invoke rake -T from inside a task?

Comment: Looking at the source for rake.rb, it looks like I should be able to invoke display_tasks_and_comments on Rake.application, but it doesn't output anything.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Invoking `rake -T` from within tasks is a bit more complicated in newer versions of rake. The options that need to be set may be derived from `rake/lib/application.rb` in method `standard_rake_options`. Basically this boils down to

```rb
Rake::TaskManager.record_task_metadata = true

task :default do
  Rake::application.options.show_tasks = :tasks  # this solves sidewaysmilk problem
  Rake::application.options.show_task_pattern = //
  Rake::application.display_tasks_and_comments
end
```

Note that `record_task_metadata` cannot be set from within the default task, as it will already be too late when the task is executed (descriptions won’t have been collected, thus those are nil and therefore no task matches the pattern). Trying to reload the Rakefile from within a task will lead to a closed loop. I assume there are performance trade ofs when always collecting metadata. If that’s an issue

```rb
task :default do
  system("rake -sT")  # s for silent
end
```

might be more suitable.

Both work for me using rake 0.9.2.2.

Comment: Also note that `Rake::TaskManager.record_task_metadata = true` must occur before any tasks are defined in the `Rakefile`.

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me using rake 10.0.4. I placed `Rake::TaskManager.record_task_metadata = true` at the top of my Rakefile and the default task at the bottom after all my regular tasks. Note: you can pass in `:describe` or `:lines` instead of `:tasks` to get different output. Personally, I prefer `:tasks` though.

Comment: If you think there should be a better way of doing this, please vote at https://github.com/ruby/rake/issues/22

Answer (score 2):

Nevermind. I found the answer once I found the right method.

In addition to calling display_tasks_and_comments you also have to set the regexp to filter the tasks you want to show or by default it will filter them all out.

To make your default task the output of rake -T use the following:

```
task :default do
  Rake.application.options.show_task_pattern = //
  Rake.application.display_tasks_and_comments()
end
```

Comment: @sidewaysmilk: See Stefan's answer above. Rake::application.options.show_tasks = :tasks fixes this problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is more complicated than a lot of people need, but this program will extract rake tasks from other rake files WITHOUT including those other rakefiles. I used it as part of a rake task that needed to validate other rakefiles.

### Main class

```
class RakeBrowser
  attr_reader :tasks
  attr_reader :variables
  attr_reader :loads
  @last_description = ''
  @namespace = ''

  include Rake::DSL

  def desc(description)
    @last_description = description
  end

  def namespace(name=nil, &block) # :doc:
    old = @namespace
    @namespace = "#{name}:#{@namespace}"
    yield(block)
    @namespace = old
  end

  def task(*args, &block)
    if args.first.respond_to?(:id2name)
      @tasks << "#{@namespace}" + args.first.id2name
    elsif args.first.keys.first.respond_to?(:id2name)
      @tasks << "#{@namespace}" + args.first.keys.first.id2name
    end
  end

  def load(filename)
    @loads << filename
  end

  def initialize(file)
    @tasks = []
    @loads = []
    Dir.chdir(File.dirname(file)) do
      eval(File.read(File.basename(file)))
    end
    @variables = Hash.new
    instance_variables.each do |name|
      @variables[name] = instance_variable_get(name)
    end
  end
end
```

### Implementation

```
desc "Show all the tasks"
task :default do
  browser = RakeBrowser.new('common.rake')

  browser.tasks.each do |task|
    puts "  " + task
  end
end
```

Complete code is at

- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fulldecent/Sites/master/Rakefile
- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fulldecent/Sites/765895e9ad6e6ebc38f6925b4c407fcd8eb5e3d6/Rakefile

Answer (score 0):

## April 2024 update:

```ruby
rake = Rake::Application.new
rake.load_rakefile
Rake::Task.tasks # Returns an array of `Rake::Task` objects
```